langchain_ollama attach image to prompt
I'm expirementing with llama 3.2 vision 11B and I'm having a bit of a rough time attaching an image, wether it's local or online, to the chat. Here's my Python code:
import io
import base64
import requests
from PIL import Image
from langchain_ollama import OllamaLLM
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate

# Define exit keywords
EXIT_KEYWORDS = ["exit", "quit", "stop", "bye", "end"]

def encode_image_to_base64(image_path: str) -> str:
    """Encodes the image at the given path to a Base64 string."""
    try:
        with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
            encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode("utf-8")
            return encoded_string
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Error: The file {image_path} was not found.")
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: Could not process the image at {image_path}. Reason: {e}")
        return None

def fetch_image_from_url(image_url: str) -> str:
    """Fetches an image from a URL and encodes it as Base64."""
    try:
        response = requests.get(image_url)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an exception for HTTP errors
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
        buffered = io.BytesIO()
        image.save(buffered, format=image.format)  # Preserve original format
        return base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: Could not fetch the image from URL. Reason: {e}")
        return None

def handle_conversation():
    """Handles the conversation loop with the user."""
    context = ""
    model = OllamaLLM(model="llama3.2-vision")
    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template("""
        Answer the question below. If an image is provided, analyze it and provide relevant information.

        Here is the conversation history: {context}

        Question: {question}

        Image (if any): {image_data}

        Answer:
    """)
    chain = prompt | model

    while True:
        user_input = input("You: ")
        if user_input.lower() in EXIT_KEYWORDS:
            print("Goodbye!")
            break
        image_data = None
        text_input = user_input.strip()

        # Check if user input includes "image:"
        if "image:" in user_input:
            try:
                text_input, image_reference = user_input.split("image:", 1)
                text_input = text_input.strip()
                image_reference = image_reference.strip()

                if image_reference.startswith("http://") or image_reference.startswith("https://"):
                    # Handle online image URL
                    image_data = fetch_image_from_url(image_reference)
                else:
                    # Handle local image path
                    image_data = encode_image_to_base64(image_reference)

                if not image_data:
                    print("Error: Unable to process the provided image.")
                    continue
            except ValueError:
                print("Error: Invalid input format. Use 'Your question here image: [path_to_image or URL]'.")
                continue

        # Invoke the model with the current context, question, and image data
        result = chain.invoke({"context": context, "question": text_input, "image_data": image_data})
        print(f"Bot: {result}")

        # Update the context with the latest user input and bot response
        context += f"\nUser: {text_input}\nAI: {result}"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    handle_conversation()

The lack of proper documentation makes this harder.
Any help/resources are much appreciated.
Simple text prompting works just fine. It's the image attaching that I'm having trouble with.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
